# Caliburn Micro navigation service resulting in nullreference exception

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10, caliburn.micro, uwp

I am using the ViewModel First approach and i have trouble navigating from one ViewModel to another.

For example, i have two folders, View and ViewModels and i have two files in each `Page1View.xaml, Page2View.xaml` and `Page1ViewModel.cs, Page2ViewModel.cs`

In my app launch i have this the line below and it works perfectly fine.

```
DisplayRootViewFor<Page1ViewModel>();
```

Now on a button click from `Page1ViewModel` event when i add the line below, i get a null reference exception.

```
_navigationService.NavitageToViewModel<Page2ViewModel>();
```

Am i missing something here? To give more information, This is a UWP application and the container that i am using is `WinRTContainer` and i have registered both the ViewModels.

Comment: First, did you make sure that `_navigationService` isn't null?

Comment: can you post a Stacktrace?

Comment: how are you initializing the NavigationService?  NavigateToViewModel is deprecated in UWP, preferred method is `_navService.For<T>().Navigate()`

Comment: I have a similar issue now. Have you solved it yet and how?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a ViewModel-first approach. Note that DisplayRootViewFor doesn't create a Frame control and doesn't set up a NavigationService.

Have a look at:
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/126

Either switch to a View-first approach, or in your root view, setup a NavigationService passing a Frame to it:

container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);